# Changing behaviour of parent virtual function based on inherited type parameter

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

I have an inheritance hierarchy with a base class and two derived classes.

In the base class, I have a virtual function:

```
virtual void interact(const Base &other) const;
```

In the derived classes, they both have the following two functions, which are necessary as the two derived classes interact different with each other (i.e. `Derived1` and `Derived1` interact differently than `Derived1` and `Derived2`) :

```
void interact(const Derived1 &other) const;
void interact(const Derived2 &other) const;
```

I want to be able to take two objects from a `vector<Base>` and call the virtual `Base` class method (e.g. `base1.interact(base2)`) and have the correct function in the derived classes to be called based on the derived types.

Is there a way I can do this, or is my approach wrong entirely?

Comment: the technique is called 'dual dispatch' there are various implementations.

Comment: Two objects in the same vector are clearly of the same type (definition of vector). To "be able to take two objects from a vector", is easy enough, but they would each be the same type. This would not seem to be your plan.  I advise against down casting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way I can do this, or is my approach wrong entirely?

The technique you are looking for is called *double dispatching*.
It is not *wrong entirely*. As an example, the pattern *visitor* is built on top of the same concept.

It follows a minimal, working example based on the details in your question:

```
#include<iostream>

struct Derived1;
struct Derived2;

struct Base {
    virtual void interact(const Base &) const = 0;
    virtual void interact(const Derived1 &) const = 0;
    virtual void interact(const Derived2 &) const = 0;
};

struct Derived1: Base {
    void interact(const Base &other) const override {
        other.interact(*this);
    }

    void interact(const Derived1 &) const {
        std::cout << "Derived1/Derived1" << std::endl;
    }

    void interact(const Derived2 &) const {
        std::cout << "Derived2/Derived1" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Derived2: Base {
    void interact(const Base &other) const override {
        other.interact(*this);
    }

    void interact(const Derived1 &) const {
        std::cout << "Derived1/Derived2" << std::endl;
    }

    void interact(const Derived2 &) const {
        std::cout << "Derived2/Derived2" << std::endl;
    }
};

void foo(const Base &lhs, const Base &rhs) {
    lhs.interact(rhs);
}

int main() {
    foo(Derived1{}, Derived1{});
    foo(Derived1{}, Derived2{});
    foo(Derived2{}, Derived1{});
    foo(Derived2{}, Derived2{});
}
```

It requires all the `interact` methods to be virtual and part of the base class.
The basic idea is that the class to which a reference to a `Base` is passed as a parameter promotes and uses itself as a (let me say) *tag* to correctly dispatch the request to the right method.
It does that by calling back the invoker and passing itself as a function parameter.